# How to configure redis to eliminate connection issue such as "No connection (requires writable - not eligible for replica)..."

Tags: redis, .net-6.0, stackexchange.redis

I am getting this exception when multiple processes adding 300K items to a Redis SET.

These processes are AWS lambdas. There are 50 lambda instances that do 10 consecutive `SADD` operations.

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection (requires writable - not eligible for replica) is active/available to service this operation: SADD MY_SET_KEY, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: 169(SE.Redis-v2.6.122.38350), PerfCounterHelperkeyHashSlot: 3358, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=32764,Min=2,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=9,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=4203,Timers=65), v: 2.6.122.38350
> at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server, T defaultValue) in /*/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2099
> at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.SetAdd(RedisKey key, RedisValue value, CommandFlags flags) in /*/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisDatabase.cs:line 1613

It seem to me that Redis service is chocking under this load. I understand that this `No connection (requires writable - not eligible for replica) is active/available` means server ran out of eligible connections.

Is there a way to to open it up to handle it?